# Find constant $k$ so the line $x+y=k$ is normal to the curve $y=x^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> For what value of the constant $k$ is the line $x+y=k$ normal to the
>   curve $y=x^2\;?$

Can anyone help me understand how to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$y = x^2 \implies y ' = 2x$: slope of tangent to curve at $x$.

$y = -x + k = (-1)x + k$, so slope of normal line is $-1$.

At what value of $x$ is $y' = 2x = -\frac 1{-1}=1\;?$

Solve for $x$, given $2x = 1$.

(Recall that the slope of the line normal to a curve at a point $(x, y)$ is the negative reciprocal of the slope of the line tangent to the curve at that same point.

Solve for $y$ using the equation of the curve, and the value you found for $x$:  $y = x^2$. That gives you $y$.

Given $x+y = k$, add $x+y$ to solve for $k$.

Comment: The slope of the line tangent to the curve at a point $(x_0, y_0)$ is the negative reciprocal of the slope of the line normal to the curve at that same point. Since normal line has slope $-1$ we need to find when the slope of the tangent line to the curve is equal to 1. I.e. When does $2x = 1$? At $x = \frac 12$.

Comment: $y=k-x$ is the normal line, whose slope is $-1$.

Comment: ahh ok I see, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have the curves $f(x)= k-x$ and $g(x)=x^2$. If the intersection is at $x^*$ the condition of normality is $g'(x^*)f'(x^*) = -1$

So $g'(x)f'(x) = -1\cdot 2x$. We can get the intersection by solving $x^*-k = f(x^*) = g(x^*) = x^{*2}$ for $x^*$.

Answer (score 0):

Slope of $y=x^2$ is $2x$, hence slope of normal is $-\dfrac 1{2x}$.

Slope of $x+y=k$ is $-1$. For this to be normal to the parabola,  $-1=-\dfrac1{2x}$, i.e. $x=\dfrac12$

At $x=\dfrac 12, y=\left(\dfrac 12\right)^2=\dfrac 14$.

Hence $k=x+y=\dfrac 34 \qquad\blacksquare$.